# What is the argument error in xmlValue?

Tags: r, xml, parsing, xpath, web-scraping

I am new to R. I want to scrape multiple pages of html pages and create a dataset with columns consisting specific data via XPath.  I found a useful scraping [tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/73547_efa9faf0166648c0809dcfa5690819ad.html).

My plan was to follow the script in the link and make it work/understand first and then customize to my website/html/xpath.

However, when I run second block in the code (Scraping the Blog Posts), I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
>     no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "xml_node".

This is the line that breaks the code:

`pages<-sapply(pages,xmlValue)`

pages variable contains a nodeset:

```
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <span class="pages">Page 1 of 25</span>
```

I assume that `xmlValue` cannot be applied to this datatype or something of that nature.

Since the code in the tutorial works for the author, I may have missed something obvious or there is a problem of the library loading sequence and related masking of functions. (although I played with that).

Any suggestion or assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Might be an RCurl issue, as XML package works fine: `doc <- htmlParse(readLines(theURL)); xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@id="leftcontent"]/div[11]/span[1]', xmlValue); # [1] "Page 1 of 25"`

Comment: @Parfait thanks. Here is the piece of codetheURL <- "http://www.r-bloggers.com/search/web%20scraping"


page_data <- html(theURL)

#get the total number of pages
pages<- page_data %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="leftcontent"]/div[11]/span[1]')
pages<-sapply(pages,xmlValue) // the code renders error on this line of code.

Comment: I completely understand where the code derives which I used. This error may be an RCurl issue as exact XPath works in XML as I show above.

Comment: @Parfait I see. Can you suggest a workaround to make the script work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `XML` as your only needed package with `xpathSApply` calls:

```
library(XML)

theURL <- "http://www.r-bloggers.com/search/web%20scraping"    
page_data <- htmlParse(readLines(theURL, warn = FALSE))
pages <- xpathSApply(doc, '//*[@id="leftcontent"]/div[11]/span[1]', xmlValue)
pages <- as.numeric(regmatches(pages, regexpr("[0-9]+$", pages)))

scrape_r_bloggers_page <- function(doc, page){

  titles <- xpathSApply(doc, '//div[contains(@id,"post")]/h2/a', xmlValue)
  descriptions <- xpathSApply(doc, '//div[contains(@id,"post")]/div[2]/p[1]', xmlValue)
  dates <- xpathSApply(doc, '//div[contains(@id,"post")]/div[1]/div', xmlValue)
  authors <- xpathSApply(doc, '//div[contains(@id,"post")]/div[1]/a', xmlValue)
  urls <- xpathSApply(doc, '//div[contains(@id,"post")]/h2/a', xmlValue)

  blog_posts_df <- data.frame(title=titles,
                              description=descriptions,
                              author=authors,
                              date=dates,
                              url=urls,
                              page=page)    
}

blogsdf <- scrape_r_bloggers_page(page_data, 1)

blogsList <- lapply(c(2:(pages-1)), function (page) {
  Sys.sleep(1)
  theURL <- paste("http://www.r-bloggers.com/search/web%20scraping/page/",page,"/",sep="")
  page_data <- htmlParse(readLines(theURL, warn = FALSE))
  scrape_r_bloggers_page(page_data, page)
})

finaldf <- rbind(blogsdf, do.call(rbind, blogsList))
```

Comment: @ Parfait , thanks , it works great. All I can suggest is the doc argument should be replaced with page_name variable. Also, the  url Xpath is retrieving the titles. Aweome!

Answer (score 0):

That "tutorial" is a weird mix of `rvest` and `XML`.  If you use `rvest`, then use the functions in that package like `html_text` instead.  The `xml2` package also works well with `rvest`, but not `XML`.   The warning message from `html` should also tell you its out of date.

```
page_data <- html(theURL)
##Warning message: 'html' is deprecated.

page_data %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="leftcontent"]/div[11]/span[1]') %>%
    html_text
[1] "Page 1 of 25"
```

Comment: S , thank you. It was indeed a tough mix of packages. The commenter above provided a great workaround.